# JQuery - слайдер контента

Tags: jquery, html, css

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста адаптивный слайдер контента.

Требования:

Адаптивный. На больших экранах отображается три блока с контентом, на меньших два, на совсем небольших один. Блоки с контентом внутри слайдера не должны обрезаться. **Для touch устройств, поддержка touch.**

Слева и справа слайдера по контроллу (стрелки prev/next).

Comment: я вот так делал, думаю  приделать сюда кнопочки next/prev и оторвать mousescroll достаточно легко
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/LZ7Eq/

Answer (score 1):

У Вас проблема в css верстке. Две следующие секции падают на следующую "строчку"

Comment: @Чад, спасибо. Основная проблема в другом (см. остальные требования к слайдеру). Адаптивную ширину для блоков настроил, теперь со всем остальным мучаюсь ...

Comment: @Astor вы слишком сильно изменили оригинальный вопрос. В таких случаях приличные люди задают второй вопрос.

Comment: @eicto, согласен. Полностью осознаю свою вину. Данный вопрос закрою и перезадам.